# Reading emails using IMAP in racket

Tags: imap, racket

I am using the following code to get make an IMAP connection. I am want to read emails. I read this documentation 
[link](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/imap.html?q=url#%28def._%28%28lib._net/imap..rkt%29._imap-get-expunges%29%29)
and could not proceed from here.

my code:

```
#lang racket

(define imap-server "*****")
(define imap-port-no ***)
(define username "*****")
(define pw "*****")
(define mailbox-name "INBOX") 

(require openssl/mzssl
         net/imap
         mzlib/etc)

(define (test-connect)
  (let ([c (ssl-make-client-context)])
    (let-values ([(in out) (ssl-connect imap-server imap-port-no c)])
      (imap-connect* in out username pw mailbox-name))))

(define-values (imap cnt recent) (test-connect))
```

I am getting the count of emails and count of recent mails from this. How to proceed from here. which functions i should call to read emails.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(imap-get-messages imap '(1) '(uid flags header body))
```

This should return a list holding the "fields" described by the flags, where `header` gives you the complete header part, and `body` is the email body.  (This is just a quick experiment to see that things are working, you'll need to know which messages to retrieve, etc -- all described in [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/imap.html).)

Here's a complete program that returns a list of the headers you want for each message in the INBOX, where each message gets an alist of the headers and their values as strings.  But note that email is not really reliable for such things -- you can receive a message regardless of what appears in the `To:` field, and there are many other header with similar semantics (for example, `Resent-To:` is similar to `To:`, sometimes there's a `Sender:` header that can be more reliable than `From:`, etc.).

```
#lang racket/base

(define imap-server "imap.somewhere.com")
(define imap-port-no 1234)
(define username "----")
(define pw "----")
(define mailbox-name "INBOX")

(require racket/list openssl/mzssl net/imap net/head)

(define (test-connect)
  (let ([c (ssl-make-client-context)])
    (let-values ([(in out) (ssl-connect imap-server imap-port-no c)])
      (imap-connect* in out username pw mailbox-name))))

(define-values [imap messages recent] (test-connect))

(define (get-interesting-headers ns)
  (for/list ([x (imap-get-messages imap ns '(header))])
    (filter-map
     (λ (x)
       (define s
         (string->symbol (string-downcase (bytes->string/utf-8 (car x)))))
       (and (memq s '(from to date subject))
            (cons s (bytes->string/utf-8 (cdr x)))))
     (extract-all-fields (car x)))))
(get-interesting-headers (for/list ([i messages]) (add1 i)))
```

Comment: I got the return value when i call imap-get-messages using just header field. I just want sender email address, receiver email address, date and subject from that return value. The return value is not a string. It is a list. I do not how to get this part of data from a list or convert this list to a string. Which piece of code should i use to get this information ? Thanks in advance.